# If key of a dictionary is not in a list, move that key and value to a new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list as below:

`fruits_exclude = ['grapes', 'banana', 'apple']`

I have two dictionaries as below:

`fruits_have = {'apple': 3, 'banana': 4, 'mango': 5, 'grapes': 5}`

`final_dict = {}`

I want to move the item `'mango': 5` into `final_dict`.

I am  trying to do it in python, but things are not working:

```
if list(fruits_have.keys()) not in fruits_exclude:
    #copy the key and value pair (item) into final_dict
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: `fruits_exclude` does not contain lists, so converting the keys to a list and checking if it's there will surely not work. You want to iterate and check ***each key*** to check if it's in the list. If not, add it with its value to the final dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final_dict = {key: val for (key,val) in fruits_have.items() if key not in fruits_exclude}
```

Comment: A single line without any explanations will hardly help for someone that was barely able to get to a solution for this issue...

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the keys of your dictionary, and add every key that is not in the `fruits_exclude` to final dict

```
fruits_exclude = ['grapes', 'banana', 'apple']
fruits_have = {'apple': 3, 'banana': 4, 'mango': 5, 'grapes': 5}
final_dict = {}
fruit_set = set(fruits_exclude)
for fruit in fruits_have.keys():
    if fruit not in fruit_set:
        final_dict[fruit] = fruits_have[fruit]
print (final_dict)
```

output:

```
{'mango': 5}
```

hope this was clear enough

and feel free to ask me for any clarifications in the comments :)